# How to use Composer repositories for Laravel Framework development

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to develop a feature for the laravel framework and want to test it, but when I try to use my forked repo, composer still uses the original code found on the official `laravel/framework` repo.

---

**Here are the steps I tried:**

1. Forked the `Laravel/Framework` repo
2. Commit changes on the `5.8` branch and pushed to my remote repo
3. Created a new Laravel project and added the following to `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/dunhamjared/framework"
    }
]
```

---

**Steps I took to try to resolve the issue:**

1. When I run `composer update laravel/framework`, the code found in the vendor folder does not reflect the changes I made on the remote branch (as mentioned above). So I ran `composer show laravel/framework -v` and composer has the correct source, which is my forked repo.
2. I then tried changing the required `"laravel/framework": "5.8.*"` to `"laravel/framework": "dev-5.8"` to force composer to use the `5.8` branch, which did not work. It instead returned:

```
λ composer update laravel/framework                                                                                                  
    1/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$ff2f7811fc3a4efdabb3f5488c3f0a32bbeccde0bb6dac9978a436f628d960f4.json         
    2/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017$633008c0f1d2475dd599d9b5e0ac5c46103d6b452c483451fd0ce94a6d9bffb4.json           
    3/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-2014$bd74535d9df6678f94563e4fa7d8b506d4db6bc8c3e69ea81df93e71ee69a131.json           
    4/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013$5919cb8ec67e8302281836d50329d62f6c7fd037e012be0394a1c3ec516c5926.json           
    5/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-2019-07$bc20f4a5234a357cd686d0d459510f182c3f29c13c4d6903c9801a8ae0fc5dd8.json        
    6/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-2018-10$c29b1b5c3d4997386cfec4894dc682cea98cdfd01ffe5d9c1203ed5c69f03c33.json        
    7/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-2019-01$cc987b846bc2d7a16278a04d1a1f3879e1f1e0d603022d89457a7dd1c2e04da7.json        
    8/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015$91097e0be14d31d5d790f3fb8c6162c1ba63c23bb1af500c7013714e6c1065af.json           
    9/11:       http://packagist.org/p/provider-2019-04$73eff0744aec57e71bdad58671769cc128fe540e19916405709fedb7fd6744b0.json        
    10/11:      http://packagist.org/p/provider-2016$16e16b6f27c823a374d703a9878f0a39dba54e9bdf311b1c4696e7111f82a180.json           
    11/11:      http://packagist.org/p/provider-2018$88778189f48920fe2aa5131da5fdff4a29cbb0006589f8b2656cc103b41b1324.json           
    Finished: success: 11, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 11                                                                         
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                               
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                                                        
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.                                                           

  Problem 1                                                                                                                          
    - The requested package laravel/framework dev-5.8 exists as laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, 5.0.30, 5.0.x-dev,
 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.41, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, dev-master, 6.0.x-dev, dev-revert-29
472-detect-environment, dev-symfony-mailer, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.2, v4.0.
3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.
1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.
1.30, v4.1.31, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2
.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.18, v4.2.19, v4.2.2, v4.2.20, v4.2.21, v4.2.22, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, 
v4.2.9, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5
.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32, v5.0.33, v5.0.34, v5.0.35, v
5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.10, v5.1.11, v5.1.12, v5.1.13, v5.1.14, v5.1.15, v5.1.16, v5.1.17
, v5.1.18, v5.1.19, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.21, v5.1.22, v5.1.23, v5.1.24, v5.1.25, v5.1.26, v5.1.27, v5.1.28, v5.1.29, v5.1.3, v5.1.30
, v5.1.31, v5.1.32, v5.1.33, v5.1.34, v5.1.35, v5.1.36, v5.1.37, v5.1.38, v5.1.39, v5.1.4, v5.1.40, v5.1.41, v5.1.42, v5.1.43, v5.1.4
4, v5.1.45, v5.1.46, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.2.0, v5.2.0-beta1, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.1
4, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.
28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.40, v5.2.
42, v5.2.43, v5.2.44, v5.2.45, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9, 5.3, v5.3.0-RC1, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v
5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.27, 
v5.3.28, v5.3.29, v5.3.3, v5.3.30, v5.3.31, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9, v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12
, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.2
6, v5.4.27, v5.4.28, v5.4.29, v5.4.3, v5.4.30, v5.4.31, v5.4.32, v5.4.33, v5.4.34, v5.4.35, v5.4.36, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, 
v5.4.8, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.
5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5
.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.42, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.5.45, v5.5.46, v5.5.47, v
5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.1
8, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.3
1, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5
.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5
.7.23, v5.7.24, v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, 
v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24,
 v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, dev-
insertIgnore] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

3. I then made a new branch (`insertIgnore`) to be sure there were no conflicts and updated `"laravel/framework": "dev-5.8"` to `"laravel/framework": "dev-insertIgnore"`. Composer fails to update and returns:

```
λ composer update laravel/framework
    1/8:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2018-10$ea2def59c63148352b45154495ba32f72de29d5e65c4448fb8429cbec37fabf0.json
    2/8:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2019-07$06b3f8b4b3fe5f3871ce9e8660e8d94aad8ea716bcfbddf54b12381ea7d3a2db.json
    3/8:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015$44490c72e9f4a2dec3280977932579be721f47258a5c5a26341d4f3977170d1d.json
    4/8:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$9dfcee6b21f4c77f4c3fff33b3ac40d0b640122e5aca826a344542fd655361fa.json
    5/8:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2019-04$995616c152a4a8333c0b8a0b4be04bc9bd971242ff011a79cf38e1c92efda923.json
    6/8:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2018$2f7310182efc83d6c31d9eb4e2a0e8641ef8fbacd3cced0e65a329406271e5aa.json
    7/8:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2016$57e0ac248d5be52ff9fa284855b06349098fc5e3b5722a0478d5f4a4ef699c7d.json
    8/8:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017$6bc569bc1c0ebc800564dbbeb0120aca2636200012824c48e55d4cbc38578532.json
    Finished: success: 8, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 8
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.32], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.0.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
   - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.32], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.0.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
  - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.32], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.0.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
 - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[dev-insertIgnore, v5.8.32].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support 6.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore
    - Installation request for laravel/framework dev-insertIgnore -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[dev-insertIgnore].
    - Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-dump-server (locked at 1.3.0, required as ^1.0) -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-dump-server[1.3.0].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `"laravel/framework": "5.8.x-dev"` under composer's `require` section worked for me.

*Thank you stancl!*